# Copy file in root folder on android to sdcard with phonegap

Tags: android, file, sqlite, cordova

I'm able to copy a file on the sdcard (Android 4.2) to another folder - BUT for some reason I cannot access a file in the /data/data/com.applicationname/ directory.
My aim is to backup the sqlite database of my application to sdcard for later retrieval.
My code:

```
 function save_db() {
   var dbfile = "file:///../app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db"; // NOT working
   var dbfile_test = "file:///../../../../sdcard/test.db"; // WORKS !
   var destDir = "file:///../../../../sdcard/backup";
   var newfile = "backup.db";

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(dbfile, function(file) {
       window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(destDir, function(destination) {
            alert("copy file "+newfile);
            file.copyTo(destination,newfile);
       },fail1)
    },fail2);
```

The function works with dbfile_test reference but NOT with dbfile - in that case I get the "fail2" error message 1 - not found. But the file is there.
So I assume it has to do with the access to the root directory ? Has the application have to have superuser rights ?  If yes, how to do that ?

Please advice - thank you !  Chris

Answer (score 0):

Answered before I read correctly. This is of course useless as it is Java based solution.

I use something like this:

```
File dbFile = new File("/data/data/package.application/databases/databasename");
File destFile = new File("sdcard/backup/backup.db");
FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(dbFile).getChannel();
FileChannel dest = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
if (dbFile.exists()) {
  dest.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
}
src.close();
dest.close();
```

Try catch block must be used as well.

Comment: Thank you anyhow - unfortunately I didn't figure out yet how to call a java function from within javascript, if that's possible at all ;-)